# VBA Application Events in Excel AddIn

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I am making an Excel 2010 AddIn and am trying to add some code to the Application Event `Application_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)`

However, my Module inside the AddIn cannot have these events. I tried making a ClassModule with the events and then initializing it on the AddIn's load. I got this idea after reading [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

Here is what I have in the AddIn's Class "EventListener:"

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "Workbook Activated:"; Wb.Name
    Call MyAddInModule.RefreshVisibility
End Sub
```

And here is what I have in the module "MyAddInModule:"

```
Public Listener As EventListener
Public myRibbonUI As IRibbonUI

' Ribbon callback : runs when ribbon is loaded
Public Sub onLoadRibbon(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    ' Get a reference to the ribbon
    Set myRibbonUI = ribbon
    Debug.Print "Ribbon Reference Set"
    Set Listener = New EventListener
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshVisibility()
    myRibbonUI.Invalidate
    Debug.Print "Ribbon Invalidated"
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this did not work. It is not possible to declare a `WithEvents` object in the normal coding module and the Class Object didn't fire as expected.

Is there a better way to have Application Events be coded into an AddIn?

Comment: In what way did it not work? The code is conceptually sound, though normally I would use the `Workbook_Open` event of the add-in to initialize the event handler.

Comment: After Openeing a few workbooks and switching between them The Immediate window did not have any "Workbook Activated" lines from the `EventListener` Class

Comment: Just noticed you're missing the bit where you assign the `Application` to your `app` variable!

Comment: Yup, That did it. I put it into the `Class_Initialize` sub It's always the silly things. Thank you!